# Lazy-load MonacoEditor

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, amd, monaco-editor, oclazyload

I have the following code to load MonacoEditor in `index.html` of my AngularJS website:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" data-name="vs/editor/editor.main" href="/monaco-editor/min/vs/editor/editor.main.css" />
<script src="/monaco-editor/min/vs/loader.js"></script>
<script src="/monaco-editor/min/vs/editor/editor.main.nls.js"></script>
<script src="/monaco-editor/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js"></script>
<script> 
    require.config({ paths: { 'vs': '/monaco-editor/min/vs' }}) 
    console.log(monaco)
</script>
```

Running the website displays well `monaco`, which will be used in a further JavaScript file.

Now, I want to load MonacoEditor by `ocLazyLoad`:

```
    .state('addin', {
        abstract: true,
        template: '<ui-view/>',
        resolve: {
            loadAddinCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load({files: [
                    "/monaco-editor/min/vs/editor/editor.main.css",
                    "/monaco-editor/min/vs/loader.js",
                    "/monaco-editor/min/vs/editor/editor.main.nls.js",
                    "/monaco-editor/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js"
                ]}).then(function () {
                    require.config({ paths: { 'vs': '/monaco-editor/min/vs' }})
                    console.log(monaco)
                })
            }]
        }
    })
```

The above code returns `ReferenceError: monaco is not defined`. Does anyone know why this happens?

Actually, I don't understand well the purpose of `require.config`, it seems to make the code much less flexible. Does anyone have an alternative to that?

Answer (score 0):

You have loaded the dependencies, yet not loaded Monaco. Try this after your `require.config`:

```
require.config({ paths: { 'vs': '/monaco-editor/min/vs' }})
require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function onMonacoLoaded(){
  console.log(monaco);
});
```